# Why I can't format code in this question?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I have just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498328/selective-usage-of-spring-securitys-csrf-filter) and I found that code formatting is just not working. This has been a long time since my last question with some code so is their any change in code formatting rules. I remember it has always worked just straight and simple but this time I just can't find out why it is not working.

Please share what are the prerequisite for code formatting and is their any change in the way we are supposed to do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ben thanks tried <code> and it worked but I am not sure why clicking on the {} image didn't work as always.

Comment: Using HTML code blocks is not the correct approach. I went ahead and fixed up the formatting (amongst other things) on that question.

Comment: It says there _"If your code appears inside a blockquote or a list, you must indent a further four spaces for every level of nesting."_ @amit; not code tags...